# how to use subquery from three tables in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have three tables like:

`customer` table

```
CUSTOMER#   LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME
1001    MORALES         BONITA
1002    THOMPSON        RYAN
1003    SMITH           LEILA
1004    PIERSON         THOMAS
1005    GIRARD          CINDY
```

`orders` table

```
ORDER#  CUSTOMER#   ORDERDATE
1000    1005    31/MAR/09
1001    1010    31/MAR/09
1002    1011    31/MAR/09
1003    1001    01/APR/09
```

`orderitems` table

```
ORDER#  ITEM#   ISBN    QUANTITY
1000    1   3437212490  1
1001    1   9247381001  1
1001    2   2491748320  1
1002    1   8843172113  2
```

And my question is: How to print the customer name who order more than 1 items(having quantity more than 1?

My sql query is like this:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM customers c
WHERE (SELECT o.quantity FROM orderitems WHERE o.quantity > 1)
```

What is the mistake in the above query?

Comment: What mistake ? You have an error ? Or you think your result is not good ?

Comment: Customers who ordered more than one item in total? Customers who ordered more then one item in one order? Customers who ordered at least one item more than once? Customers who ordered at least one item with a quantity greater than 1 in at least one order? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname
from customer c
    join orders o on c.customer# = o.customer#
    join orderitems oi on o.order# = oi.order#
group by c.firstname, c.lastname
having sum(oi.quantity) > 1
```

Comment: can you please do it without using the join function. i mean only using subquery

Comment: @Cool I can, but may I ask why? What's wrong with doing joins?

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your query:

**1) You are not comparing anything really.**

```
where (select o.quantity from orderitems where o.quantity > 1)
```

the query result are rows with quantities greater then 1. So you may get

```
where (2
       3
       4)
```

As you can plainly see, this makes no sense.

**2) Your subquery is not related to the customers record in question.**

It merely looks for orders with great quantities, regardless of for which customer.

**Solution for orderitems with quantity > 1**

(It is not really clear whether you want this or whether you want to look at sums and whether these sums shall be per customer, per order, per item or whatever. See my question in the comments section of your request.)

You can do this with `EXISTS` or `IN`. For instance:

```
select firstname, lastname
from customers
where customer# in 
(
  select customer# 
  from order
  where order# in (select order# from orderitems where quantity > 1)
);
```

Comment: @Cool Gratitude is expressed on this site through upvotes/accepts. This should be the accepted answer (upvote from me).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below :

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname
from customers c
join orders on c.CUSTOMER#=orders.CUSTOMER#
join orderitems on orders.ORDER#=orderitems.ORDER#
group by c.firstname, c.lastname
having sum(orderitems.quantity)>1
```

You can do it without `join` also like below :

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname
from customers c
where 1 < (
            select sum(quantity) from orderitems where ORDER# in 
                (
                    select ORDER# from orders where CUSTOMER# = c.CUSTOMER#
                ) 
            group by ORDER#)
```

Comment: can you please do it without using the join function. i mean only using subquery

Comment: @Cool - Did you check ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.first, c.Lastname, oi.quantity from customers c
inner join Orders o on c.customer = o.customers
inner join OrderItems oi on oi.order = o.order
where oi.quantity >= 1
```

I guess this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: can you please do it without using the join function. i mean only using subquery

Comment: Select c.first, c.Lastname, oi.quantity from customers c
where c.customer in (select o.customer from Orders o 
where o.Order in (select oi.Order from OrderItems where Quantity > 1))


This is done without joins. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two conditions in `HAVING` to satisfy the condition of `who order more than 1 items(having quantity more than 1)`

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname
FROM customer c
JOIN orders o ON c.customer# = o.customer#
JOIN orderitems oi ON o.order# = oi.order#
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname
HAVING SUM(oi.quantity) > 1 AND SUM(oi.ITEM#) > 1
```

Comment: can you please do it without using the join function. i mean only using subquery